# Loop, closure and addEventListener in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry for that not so specific title because my English is not good enough to describe this situation clearly in the title.

I have a code like this:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName( "test" );
var myFunc = function( e ) { 
  e = e + 1; 
};

for ( var i = 0, l = e.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var t = e[ i ];
    var j = 0;
    (function( n, num ){
        num = 0;
        n.addEventListener("click", function() {
          myFunc( num );
          console.log( num )
        });
    }( t, j ));
}
```

My intention is to make variable `j`'s value to increase but the result I still get `j=0` after everytime `.test` is clicked.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qepibi/13)

Comment: Why do you redeclare `j` each time, in every loop?

Comment: Can you rewrite your code so that you have meaningfull variable names and not a bunch of same-named vars?

Comment: `myFunc()` doesn't do anything. Numbers aren't passed by reference in JavaScript.

Comment: don't understand what you're trying to achieve in your code, could you elaborate?

Comment: How do you expect j to be incremented in any way?

Comment: @acontell This is a reduced test case of a project I am doing, and I need to increase `j` to `j+1` after each click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that JavaScript does not pass primitive values (like numbers) by reference, but by value. The `myFunc` function *must* return something, you cannot assign to its arguments to change "outside" values.

Here's a more modern approach, based on the reasonable assumption that browsers that support `getElementsByClassName()` also support `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

The following creates one closure with `num` per HTML element.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("test"),
    myFunc = function(e) { 
        return e += 1; 
    };

[].slice.call(elems).forEach(function (elem) {
    var num = 0;
    elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
        num = myFunc(num);
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/\d*$/, num);
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="test">Test 0</button>
<button class="test">Test 0</button>
<button class="test">Test 0</button>
```

---

Javascript *does* pass objects by reference, so with a slight change this would work:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("test"),
    myFunc = function(properties) { 
        properties.num += 1; 
    };

[].slice.call(elems).forEach(function (elem) {
    var properties = {
            num: 0
        };
    elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
        myFunc(properties);
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/\d*$/, properties.num);
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="test">Test 0</button>
<button class="test">Test 0</button>
<button class="test">Test 0</button>
```